# How to concatenate two array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have labels of 3 images and also have their euclidean distances from test images. i want to bring corresponding distance together with their label.
labels are following.

```
[[array(['morgan freeman'], dtype='<U14')]

 [array(['ahsan khan'], dtype='<U10')]

 [array(['tom cruise'], dtype='<U10')]
```

i tried concatenation using  `a= np.concatenate((p,q),axis=0)` where **p** is distance like `[2554,333,453]` and **q** is labels which is mention above. but it gives mee error.

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)

Comment: the first array that is `q` has 3 dimension,whereas `p` has one dimensions, make the `q` a one dimension array first

Answer (score 0):

let's see when you want to merge two arrays there are 2 ways to do it:

q:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

p:

```
['image1' 'image2' 'image3']
```

1) Append one to the right of the other or vice versa.

In order to merge p with q we'll need to translate p to be vertical: `p.reshape((p.size, 1))`

```
[['image1']
 ['image2']
 ['image3']]
```

now:
`print(np.concatenate((q, p.reshape((p.size, 1))), axis=1))` or `print(np.hstack((q, p.reshape((p.size, 1)))))`

```
[['1' '2' '3' 'image1']
 ['4' '5' '6' 'image2']
 ['7' '8' '9' 'image3']]
```

2) Append one to the bottom of the other or vice versa:
It's easier:
Here you must be careful. vtsack and concatenate differs a little bit here.
You can directly vstack these two arrays as:`print(np.vstack((q, p)))`

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['4' '5' '6']
 ['7' '8' '9']
 ['image1' 'image2' 'image3']]
```

But in order to concatenate you'll need to have two arrays with same dimensions.
q has a dimension number of 2 and p has a dimension number of 1. So basically if you make the p a row of a 2D array you can do concatenate: `print(np.concatenate((q, [p])))`

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['4' '5' '6']
 ['7' '8' '9']
 ['image1' 'image2' 'image3']]
```

I hope that helps.